# Three table model relationship in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I've got a CAkePHP 1.2 site. I've got three related Models/tables:
A Comment has exactly one Touch, a Touch has exactly one Touchtype.

In each model, I have a belongs to, so I have
Comments belongs to Touch, Touch belongs to Touchtype.

I'm trying to get a list of comments that includes information about the touch stored in the touchtype table.

```
$this->Comment->find(...)
```

I pass in a fields list to the find(). I can grab fields from Touch and Comment, but not TouchType. Does the model connection only go 1 level? I tried tweaking recursive, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh. This was a simple matter of recursive.

Answer (score 1):

yup. you might want to try increasing $this->Comment->recursive to 2